# Конфликт 301 редиректов

Tags: .htaccess, редирект

Перенес сайт на новый домен. В htaccess на старом сайте настроил вида 2 редиректа:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^old-site.ru$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://new-site.org/$1 [R=301,L]
```

и

```
Redirect 301 /page-from-old-site https://new-site.org/category/page-from-new-site/
Redirect 301 /page-from-old-site-2 https://new-site.org/category/page-from-new-site-2/
...
```

Почему-то работает только один из видов редиректов. При включенном первом, второй редирект отправляет с http://old-site.ru/page-from-old-site на https://new-site.org/page-from-new-site/ минуя категорию, вследствие чего получаю 404 ошибку. Что-то делаю не так?

Comment: Попробуйте поменять местами строки с редиректами?

Comment: пробовал местами менять. Не работает. Вообще, работает только в том случае если я на новом сайте ставлю те же 301 редиректы на страницы. Но в таком случае получается двойной редирект и я не знаю как это повлияет на выдачу в гугле/яндексе.

Answer (score 1):

У вас до этих строк управление не доходит

```
Redirect 301 /page-from-old-site https://new-site.org/category/page-from-new-site/ 
Redirect 301 /page-from-old-site-2 https://new-site.org/category/page-from-new-site-2/
```

Так как применяются эти правила

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^old-site.ru$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://new-site.org/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Вынесите строки Redirect 301 выше чтобы они проверялись сначала.

Comment: не помогает, но стоит закоментить редирект на сайт, как срабатывают редиректы на страницы.